# My iTunes account got hacked and someone used it to buy in-app purchase. How could that happen?

Tags: passwords, ios

The account was hacked, I found out in my credit card statement and Apple support gave me refund which is nice. I wonder how it happened, and if there are even more serious risks that I don't know.

The iTunes account is only for a very old iPad which has no iOS update anymore. I never bought any app or even entered the iTunes account username and password in the last two years. A few months ago I tried to buy an iPhone 6s Plus and did use this account to login browsers in computers, but those are computers at home with updated antivirus and Windows updates. Any clue, and what should I do for protection and cleanup?

Comment: I would make sure you choose a more secure password.  I'm surprised at this though since generally you have to answer security questions to download music from a different device than is recognized.  For Apple anyway.

Comment: The stolen one was in-app purchase, so may be not security questions would be needed?

Comment: Possibly.  If you have access to your account I would ensure that your security questions are up to date, and your password has been changed to something secure.

Comment: How could this happen? My original password was pretty long already like 12 digits.

Comment: Did you use the same password somewhere else?

Comment: No, not at all, it is a random string of charter and number that I write down somewhere at home.

Comment: I just use avast free and malwarebytes with latest update to scan once, nothing risky found. Anything can I do to prevent or solve any possible threads? I have a notebook that I only use for serious stuff link e-banking and I am worry that is affected.

Comment: The most common way an apple account is hacked is through the password reset system. The second most common way is simply through support. Contact Apple support and see with them how to recover. Next time: don't trust "security" questions (treat them as passwords: use random, unique strings as answers) and enable 2-step authentication. That's not 100% (since a bit of social engineering can usually fool an apple support person into granting access to your account) but that's the best you can do.

Comment: The Apple support told me the purchase is done by another apple account that is "linked" to my apple account. Any idea how someone can use this to steal money and get in app purchase?

Comment: If you have any family members that are under your Family account that are authorized as people who can purchase things this could have happened.  Check your iCloud settings, specifically the Family portion.

Comment: I see, but I didn't set it up as family account and didn't authorized any linked account....

Comment: Pursue this further with Apple support and don't accept BS answers.

Comment: You need to set a good passphrase instead of passeords. They dont need to be very complex but long and complex. For example: "1200GiantSnailsAreEatingMyLettuce" or "OhMyGod!IsThatJervasDudleyOverThere?" would be fairly good passwords. Try to make them surreal and unique so people cannot guess them. Try to use Upper and Lower case, numbers and if you use non-latin typesets other chars like Ä, ß or cyrillic.

Comment: I dont know how Apple deals with this but you should enable 2 Factor Authrntication. This will keep your account secure even when someone stole your credentials.

Comment: Look like it is a security hole of Family Sharing, anyone has detail about it? Easy guessing Security question answers can let this happens?

Answer (score 2):

You said that you are worried that your notebook might be infected in addition to worrying about your iTunes/Apple account being compromised.  That, in combination with the fact that I always assume the worst will be the basis/context for my answer to you.

I always assume the worst as I stated so here is what I would do:

1)  Wipe your notebook; if you suspect any kind of compromise or any kind of malicious infection at all then your safest bet is to wipe it and start over.  Are there other options here such as trying different scans to try to "potentially" find the compromise?  Sure.  Could it take forever, and possibly not yield fruitful results?  More than likely.

2) Change your iTunes/AppleID password right away.  Create another string of randomly generated characters that include the usual: uppers, lowers, special characters, and numbers.  May I suggest a password manager?  If for nothing else, use the password manager to generate a random password as most of them have this capability built-in to them now.

3) Update your security questions on the account to completely different questions and answers than before.

4) Turn on Apple's two-factor authentication.  This is purely OPTIONAL, however it's a great additional layer of security nonetheless.

5)  Practice safe browsing and computing habits going forward.  I know this is pretty broad and generalized, but the more you're aware of what sites and services you visit and use and their practices as well as their reputation while online, or even offline for that matter, the safer you'll stay in the long run.

These are just the general overview items.  Please let me know if you'd like any more in-depth.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. How do you personal protect your computers Brad? What do you use other thank keep point 5 in mind?

Comment: Things like using a virtual machine (VM) for online banking or other sensitive online activities that involve your PII or financial information, using multiple layers of antimalware defense like you already do (using Avast and Malwarebytes is a great start) but try adding to your layers by using EMET (if you run Windows which I assume you do), Secunia and Windows Firewall just to name a few for extra defense.  Also, add some DNS/web filtering to your arsenal by using a company like OpenDNS on your home router/firewall.  These are just a few suggestions, so make sure to do your own research.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Should I use Orbit or Malwarebytes? Just Avast would not protect stuff like keylogging?

Comment: Avast and Malwarebytes would be my recommendation.  They do two different (somewhat similar in some ways) types of scanning which is good because it allows for versatility.

Comment: Thanks but Malwarebytes free version doesn't provide free real time protection.....

Comment: Pay the $20 for the real time scans and added protection and then lean on Avast for the other portion of scanning.  Also, install EMET as I suggested and use recommended settings with it.  Putting those into place and a good web proxy/dns filter will help greatly.  Look up highly rated/reviewed browser add-ins and extensions that do things like block ads as well.

Comment: I see, that's how to do a great protection. Does this setup scan all possible thread that may be already in my computers? I don't know if any virus/malware can hide themselves if they have already been inside my computers.